# How to hide env variables in _app file in Next Js

Tags: next.js, environment-variables

In the rest of the pages, I accessed env variables using getServerSideProps, but this is not supported in _app. How can I use env variables and remain secret in the client side?

Comment: For what exact use-case are you trying to use secret env-variables inside _app? You cannot have secret client-side environment variables, because they are being exposed to the users

Comment: I have    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>  and i want to hide this endpoint.

Comment: What is that provider for, and why do you want to hide ```endpoint```? You'll need a different approach to the problem because there's no way to hide client-side code